# How to swap 2 view controllers in a UINavigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift4.1

I have 2 `UIViewControllers`, `UIViewControllerA` and `UIViewControllerB` in a `UINavigationController` stacked in this manner -> `[UIViewControllerA, UIViewControllerB]`. 
Now instead of popping `UIViewControllerB` to reach `UIViewControllerA`, I want to swap the 2 objects in navigation stack.

So I do this :

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([UIViewControllerB, UIViewControllerA], animated: true)
```

After this when I query my navigation stack, **there is only 1 view controller i.e. `[UIViewControllerA]`**

Question 1: Why I cannot find UIViewControllerB as root view controller?

Question 2: I want to again swap the 2 view controllers to reach UIViewControllerB. How to achieve this, if possible?

Comment: First
Please, answer to the question.
Why you need do this?
Can you describe you flow?
I guess, we can find solution using the next possible solutions: unwind segues, push a new one controller.
All data we can pass to another controller instance if it need.

Comment: If we use unwind segue or pop the view controller, the temporary data created in the UIViewControllerB will be lost or will have to be saved somewhere. But due to existing complexities, I am trying to avoid that. The purpose of swapping is so that user can just peek into the UIViewControllerA and return back to UIViewControllerB. So I am trying to save the effort of persisting data of UIViewControllerB when the user moves back to the previous viewcontroller i.e. UIViewControllerA. I hope this gives a clear picture of the use case.